# Flex rule exclusion

Tags: flex-lexer

I need a way for flex to ignore words that are written between {} as if they were comments.

I tried to use im my code

```
comment [{a-zA-Z}]*
{comment} ;
```

but it just ignores(recognizes) the "{" and "}" and what's written inside is still being recognized as part of the grammar.

what is written between the braces is a comment in a programming language

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mre]. Two lines completely out of context cannot provide enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: It should be `comment {[a-zA-Z]*}`, or possibly `comment {[a-zA-Z]+}` if you don't want to allow empty comments, for a start.

Comment: @user207421: that's certainly better, but it still won't handle comments which include whitespace, which is probably what's at play here. Because as it stands, the problem is that the pattern matches too much, not too little, and part of the mystery is why it is not causing identifiers to be incorrectly ignored. It's all too much guessing of something which could easily be clarified by OP.

Comment: Thanks guys, what I had to do was insert the line "{"[^}\n]*"}" ; and delete what I had done

Comment: @rici Agreed, but he did say 'words that are written between {}', which I took literally.

Comment: @Jonas: That's great. It's always best when you solve your own problems. Please either write an answer yourself, or delete your question if you don't think its answer will help others. (In order to be useful, your answer should explain what was wrong with what you had originally and how your change solved what was wrong.)